# MongodB in operator return on blank array when it should not

Tags: javascript, mongodb, coffeescript, meteor

I have a template function in coffeescript running on the client:

```
Template.leftNav.starred = () ->
   user = Meteor.user()
   if ! user 
        return
   else
        starredPages = user.profile.starredPages
        starred =  Entries.find({ _id :{in: starredPages}}).fetch()
```

`Meteor.user()` returns

```
Object {_id: "AHSwfYgeGmur9oHzu", profile: Object}
  _id: "AHSwfYgeGmur9oHzu"
  profile: Object
  starredPages: Array[4]
     0: "asdasdasdasdasd"
     1: "abc123"
     2: "blobby"
     3: "bxSbMgszYxbCqDonF"
```

and `Meteor Entries.find({})` returns:

```
Entries
     Meteor.Collection {_makeNewID: function, _transform: null, _manager: Meteor._LivedataConnection, _collection: LocalCollection, _name: "entries"…}
    _collection: LocalCollection
    _savedOriginals: null
    docs: Object
        Wkxxpapm8bbiq59ig:
            _id: "M3vDJNMZJjBDfrc7D"
        bxSbMgszYxbCqDonF:
            _id: "bxSbMgszYxbCqDonF"
```

Executing the code in the template function:

```
starredPages = user.profile.starredPages
starred =  Entries.find({ _id :{in: starredPages}}).fetch()
```

`starred` returns as a blank array even though the `bxSbMgszYxbCqDonF` value in the starredPages array matches the `_id` value in the `Entries.docs` collection array.

Why is this and how to a make it return the matches between the `starredPages` array and the `_id`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$in`

```
starred =  Entries.find({ _id :{$in: starredPages}}).fetch()
```

Simple typo ;)